# How to print parts of an 2d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Im not asking for the answer per say im asking necessarily what would i need to change in order to print out sections of a 2d array for example if the array has 5 rows and 5 columns how would i print out the last 3 rows and last three columns.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

public class multiplication {
    static int a,b;
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    a =input.nextInt();
    b = input.nextInt();

 int[][] matrix = new int[a][b];


matrix = timesTable(a,b);


for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) {    
        System.out.print(" "+matrix[row][column] + "\t|");  
        }
      System.out.println(); 
      }


}




public static int[][] timesTable(int r, int c)
{
    int [][] yes = new int[c][c];
    for ( r = 0; r < yes.length ; r++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < yes[r].length; c++)
        {

                 yes[r][c] = (r+1)*(c+1);

        }
             }


    return yes;
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the operation you want to have occur?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What do you want to input and what is the desired output? Give some examples. Also explain what your code does instead of just dumping it, thanks.

Comment: your requirement is unclear. "so if i was to type in 4 and 4 it would print" it doesn't sound informative, please rephrase your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
if((row = 0 && col > 1) ||( row > 1 && col != 1)) {
    //print
}
```

This logic should work for your example. But I don't understand what you're trying to do.
Can you try explain a bit more what you want to do ?

Edit: you might wanna check this. [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) bottom of the page with arraycopy and arraymanipulation

Comment: What i mean is i am making a multiplication table how ever what i would like to do is instead of printing the whole table i would like to print portion so instead of seeing 1 and 1 1 and 2 multiply its starts off at 5 and 5 being multiplied

Answer (score 0):

Is the goal of this exercise to build the matrix and then print the matrix -or- do you simply need to display the desired output? *I assume this is a class assignment.*

*Hint: Think about this .. if you enter 2 & 5, do you want a 2x5 matrix or a 4x4 matrix? It's important when you alloc your matrix size.*

Comment: the goal is to print out the matrix from a 4x4 matrix starting from 2 ending at 5 in both the column and row

Comment: can you explain to me exactly how i am doing it incorrectly in an example code

Comment: @YaMom I understand the output you want.  I just wanted to know whether the exercise required you to build a matrix and then print, or if you could do one set of nexted for loops to display the output.

Comment: You input values a & b; e.g. 2 & 5.  Next you perform "new[a][b]".  That will not give you a 4x4.

Comment: Based on your update, if I enter 2000 & 2004, instead of a 5x5 matrix, you will allocate a 2004x2004 matrix.

Comment: what im trying to do is not get a 2004 by 2004 matrix but get a metrix with a min of a and a max of b so if they input 3 and 4 it will be a 2x2 matrix that shows the multiple of 3*3 3*4 4*3 and 4*4

Comment: Yes, I understand.  So let me be more explicit.  You read a=2000 & b=2004, then you do "new int[b][b]" which is "new int[2004][2004]".  Thus, you need to first determine how big you want the matrix; e.g. c=b-a would give you c=2004-2000 which gives you c=5.  Now you can do "new int[c][c]" and you have your 5x5 matrix.

Comment: alright so how can i go about filling the matrix with the said muliples

Comment: @YaMom Do you need any other help with this question, or would you like to accept the answer?